# Web based client for Amazon S3

Tags: web-applications, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

We are looking for a secure online solution to access our files stored on Amazon S3. We have about 3K files, mostly media and documents, that we need to make available to our employees on the move. We don't want to develop anything in-house if there is an existing solution.

Please note that our employees are not technologically minded, so a simple web based upload/download GUI would work the best.

Comment: You can use https://www.s3edit.com Works just fine for me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [S3fm](https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3fm/index.html), a free web-based file manager for Amazon S3.

Strictly speaking, it's not a "hosted" solution so you don't have to share your credentials with a 3rd party web site. It's a stand-alone Ajax app that loads directly from Amazon S3 and runs in your browser. Works with all major browser/OS combinations.

Next version will allow user management and file sharing with non-AWS users.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. That's exactly what we were looking for. Hadn't come across it before.

Comment: Not working properly for iPad safari as of Sept 2012

Comment: Seems dead, now points to GoDaddy.

Comment: now at http://s3.amazonaws.com/s3fm/index.html

Comment: Doesn't work for me :'( It stuck on "Loading..." in Firefox.

Comment: Haven't been able to get this to work, but looks promising

Comment: the maintainer's email address is failing, tho.

Comment: refused to work for me because I'm not in the EU

Comment: it is not a secure site and it is asking for my AWS credentials :(

Comment: It is alive, but seems to be abandonware. Given email does not work. Don't know if support button works. @Alex can you comment?

Comment: You can use https://www.s3edit.com Works just fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you can very easily set up browser access (either public or secured with AWS credentials) to an S3 bucket so that the files are accessible via HTTP, without the need for a plugin.

There are a few nice standalone clients that give you an explorer-type view of an S# bucket, rather like WinSCP etc. do for FTP or SSH accessible directories.  Try [Cloudberry](http://cloudberrylab.com) for Windows or [CyberDuck](http://cyberduck.ch) for Mac.

If you want a more functional tool, maybe something cross platform and easy for your employees or IT folks to set up, take a look at [JungleDisk](http://jungledisk.com); it lets you mount S3 directories as virtual drives on Windows, Mac or Linux, and also takes care of scheduled backups from your client machines to S3 if that would be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We want our users to be able to browse/select available files and directories online.

Answer (score 2):

Does it really need to be hosted, or just easily accessible by your employees?  There's a firefox extension called [S3 Fox](http://www.s3fox.net) that embeds an excellent S3 file manager into firefox, and works on all platforms for which firefox is available.

Edit:

There is [S3browse.com](http://s3browse.com), although I've never tried it.  I would of course be very wary of any web-based interface to S3 that I didn't control as you will have to give them your access identifiers and once someone else has them your account is ripe for abuse.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That wouldn't work unfortunately. We need a solution that would work online with any computer/browser out of the box, without any additional instalations or configuration requred from our employees and customers. Otherwise we could use any available windows client.

Comment: Thanks for your word of caution. Aparently S3fm is not a "hosted" solution, so hopefully it won't have this issue.

Comment: Nick, check out S3fm (http://www.s3fm.com/). Although it's an online solution, you don't actually share you credentials with a 3rd party web site. The app is 100% Ajax, so it loads from Amazon S3, runs in you browser and communicates back directly using the S3 protocol. This way you credentials are secure and never leave your computer.

Comment: How do you know _for sure_ that it doesn't call home somewhere as well?  Just curious...

Answer (score 2):

There was a [Amazon S3 Client](http://www.typhooncloud.com) called typhoonCloud that is on the market.  It is currently only a Windows offering, but has great uploading, simple downloading, and online interactivity with files.  You could create whatever sub-accounts you want, and so long as your employees have the software, give them the appropriate launch codes, and they can view, upload, and download whatever files are appropriate to their own account.  Or, just give them one overall account.  Not sure if that is what you are looking for or not, but the online browser is very simple, upload is super fase, and it may be a good choice if your employees like a simple UI.

## Edit:

**Please Note: Support for typhoonCloud has been discontinued.**

We STRONGLY encourage all typhoonCloud users to remove any content stored with typhoonCloud. In the future, access to typhoonCloud will stop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more functional cross-platform tool to handle your Amazon S3, you can have a look at [CrossFTP Pro](http://www.crossftp.com/). It is a FTP style tool to process FTP, SFTP, WebDav, Sun Cloud, and Amazon S3 protocols. It provides both the standalone version on desktop and applet version in the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who find this on google and aren't satisfied with s3fm check out s3commnader at https://github.com/nimbis/s3commander. Entirely client-side and open source.